# Git ignore doesn't work with files starting with underscore

Tags: git

Why does `public/_test.php` show as being changed?

```
[Michael@devserver www]$ cat .gitignore
logs
vendor
src/twig
public/_test.php
.env
[Michael@devserver www]$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   public/_test.php
#       modified:   server.php
#       modified:   src/App.php
#       modified:   src/ServerApp.php
#       modified:   src/classes/Main.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[Michael@devserver www]$
```

Comment: Have you started to ignore the file once it has already been tracked?

Comment: @choroba  Possibly.  But I don't believe I experience that same behavior with other files which don't start with an underscore.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the underscore?  Sorry...

Comment: It's the file beginning with an underscore, I ran into the same problem. Wouldn't even work escaping it with \\_filename